# Calling a boolean method inside the where clause of a Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, methods

I've a query in Linq that calls a method inside the where clause... 
Here's the code:

```
it = {my iter}
{
   ...
   return from l in lifts
          where(compare(l.Trip.Start, it.Start, startRadius)) 
          select l;
}

private bool compare(POI a, POI b, int radius)
{
    return (((b.Position.X.Value - radius < a.Position.X.Value) 
              && (a.Position.X.Value < b.Position.X.Value + radius))
              && ((b.Position.Y.Value - radius < a.Position.Y.Value)
              && (a.Position.Y.Value< b.Position.Y.Value + radius)));
}
```

but the query returns every time all the lifts list. Why the method compare returns every time true?
Where I'm wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Does your `compare` method work correctly when you call it outside of the LINQ query?

Comment: Yes, the method does his work.

Comment: What do you mean by "all the lifts list"?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Sqrt( (X1-X2)*(X1-X2) + (Y1-Y2)*(Y1-Y2) ) < radius`

Comment: The entire list set... When it has to return at least some values

Comment: It returns the entire list? Make a Console.WriteLine call at the beginning of method to see if it's being called

Comment: Seems like you're looking for all l in lifts within radius to it.Start.  If so, perhaps you should be working with a square of the x and y differences:  compare(a, b, r) { return ((b.x - a.x) * (b.x - a.x) + (b.y - a.y) * (b.y - a.y)) < (r * r); }

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint at the start of your `compare` method and confirm that the `a` and `b` parameters are what you expect them to be?

Comment: @MattBurland Ok I'll try

Comment: @MattBurland The `Console.WriteLine()` does not write nothing... Seems that the method is not called neither...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has to be something wrong with your data or `compare` method.
There is nothing magical in how `where` works. I bet that if you place `return false` in `compare` method, returned list will be empty.

**Update**: you should consider @Jacob Proffitt answer too  if you aren't sure of `it.Start` value at the time of query execution (I don't know why it is down-voted).

Try to replace LINQ query with simple `foreach` loop and step through code with debugger.

As suggested in comments, in `compare` method you probably want to measure if two points are within some range. So:

```
double x1 = a.Position.X.Value; 
double y1 = a.Position.Y.Value; 
double x2 = b.Position.X.Value; 
double y2 = b.Position.Y.Value; 

return ((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2)) < (r*r);
```

Comment: Sqrt isn't really needed (kind of expensive for this), since you can simply compare against radius * radius.  I'm assuming numbers are well under overflow range.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was in the compare method! Thank you all!